# Why doesn't "Hello #{#'world'}" return anything?

Tags: ruby, irb

My IRB console output.

```
1.9.3p385 :005 > "Hello #{#'world'}"
1.9.3p385 :006 >
```

Shouldn't this return `Hello`? What is that happening? Is this an error?

Comment: It's the same with `puts`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the second `"#"` character. That is making the rest of the line a comment. Therefore, it is not a complete line.

```
"Hello #{'world'}"
```

Comment: I wanted to comment out `'world'`

Comment: Yes, but you also commented out the rest of the line, which isn't valid (as in, you also commented out your closing braces and quotes).

Comment: So how you comment it out?

Comment: You probably shouldn't comment out just that part of a line, but you have a couple options. One would be assign the value on a different line and comment that out. Another would be to put "Hello #{nil && 'World'}" (which is pretty ugly).

Comment: Are you looking for an equivalent of <!--  comment --> ?  I don't think Ruby supports that type of comment.

Comment: Ruby certainly does not have any option for commenting a specific section.

Answer (score 3):

Like rjenkins says, " therefore it is not a complete line."

To prove this, and to complete the line in ERB do this:

> Type `"Hello #{#'world'}"`, then press Enter. Then type `}"` and press Enter. You shall see what happens then, once you have "completed the line".